# Checking if words with an accent was displayed

Tags: android, ruby, calabash, calabash-android

In automated tests, I need to know how I can check if words with an accent was displayed. I performed automated tests as below:

**file.feature**

```
# encoding: utf-8

Feature: Cálculo de triângulo

Scenario: Calculando um triângulo equilátero
    Given que estou na tela do TrianguloApp
    When eu preencher o campo Lado 1 com "3"
        And eu preencher o campo Lado 2 com "3"
        And eu preencher o campo Lado 3 com "3"
        And eu clicar em Calcular
    Then a mensagem "O triângulo é Equilátero" será exibida
```

**file_steps.rb**

```
Given(/^que estou na tela do TrianguloApp$/) do
    element_exists("* text:'TrianguloApp'")
end

When(/^eu preencher o campo Lado 1 com "(.*?)"$/) do |lado1|
      enter_text "* id:'txtLado1'", "#{lado1}"
end

When(/^eu preencher o campo Lado 2 com "(.*?)"$/) do |lado2|
      enter_text "* id:'txtLado2'", "#{lado2}"
end

When(/^eu preencher o campo Lado 3 com "(.*?)"$/) do |lado3|
      enter_text "* id:'txtLado3'", "#{lado3}"
end

When(/^eu clicar em Calcular$/) do
      touch("* id:'btnCalcular'")
end

Then(/^a mensagem "(.*?)" será exibida$/) do |mensagem|
     element_exists("* O triângulo é Equilátero")
end
```

The result is as in the image below.

[image: result of the automated test]

The error occurred because of trying to verify that the phrase `O triângulo é Equilátero` was displayed on the screen.

Comment: Welcome to SO, language which is preferred or only one required here is English...!

Comment: Your image is unlegible, capture only about the left half of the screen instead of the window. And reduce the code to the strict minimum, give the directory structure where you put your files, the version of RSpec, etc, all we need to reproduce the problem. We can't help with so few details. And I don't understand _sentence ... was displayed on the screen_. The test is not going to watch the screen, but check some data in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to validate the text `O triângulo é Equilátero`

I changed the command `element_exists` to `macro %Q|I should see "#{text}"|`

See how it got:

`Entao(/^a mensagem "(.*?)" será exibida$/) do |mensagem|
    macro %Q|I should see "#{mensagem}"|
end`

Source: http://testmunk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/steps.html

Answer (score 0):

Well your statement is missing the text:

```
element_exists("* text:'O triângulo é Equilátero'")
```

That might be all you need to get this working, however if you problem is the accents then you could find the element first though a different identifier then check the text.

```
the_text = query("* id:some_id", "text")

expect(the_text).to eql 'O triângulo é Equilátero'
```

The expect is from rspec https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations